# category shows white screen in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

category shows white screen in wordpress website instead of associated posts.
[Link for the same](https://www.automationlaboratories.com/category/jenkins/)

Permalink Settings settings defined is custom[image: Image for Permalink Settings]

Comment: did this happen after changing the permalinks structure? Was something done on the page after which this problem appeared ?

Comment: i changed the permalinks structure and saved.

Comment: can you include the code inside you .htaccess file. Do you also have broken links to pages/post

Comment: I got a solution it was All in one SEO plugin which was messing up with the category now it is working fine thanks for support

Comment: Maybe a good idea to describe the solution as answer :) - name of the plugin, problem - solution